# Que peut donc de l'esprit la plus vaste étendue ?

Tags: syntaxe, poésie

Du [*poème sur le Désastre de Lisbonne*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Po%C3%A8me_sur_le_d%C3%A9sastre_de_Lisbonne/%C3%89dition_Garnier) de Voltaire :

> Il les a tous détruits, et se combat lui-même :
>
> Semblable à cet aveugle en butte aux Philistins,
>
> Qui tomba sous les murs abattus par ses mains.
>
> **﻿Que peut donc de l’esprit la plus vaste étendue ?**
>
> Rien : le livre du sort se ferme à notre vue.

Tout le poème est rempli d'inversions, étant que Voltaire privilégie toujours la rime, mais celle-ci me laisse un peu incertain. Je comprends bien que « que peut donc » veut dire « que peut donc faire », mais c'est le sujet du verbe que j'ai des difficultés à repérer. Est-ce « la plus vaste étendue de l'esprit » ? Si c'est le cas, comment est-ce qu'une « étendue » pourrait agir ?

Answer (score 3):

J'ai également du mal à comprendre le sens de ce passage. Je pense que la phrase sans inversion est :

> Que peut donc la plus vaste étendue de l'esprit ?

Qu'on doit, selon moi, comprendre comme :

> De quoi est capable la plus vaste étendue de l'esprit ?

La source que tu as donné a une note quelques vers plus loins qui semble concerner tout le passage :

> Il est clair que l’homme ne peut par lui même être instruit de tout cela. L’esprit humain n’acquiert aucune notion que par l’expérience ; nulle expérience ne peut nous apprendre ni ce qui était avant notre existence, ni ce qui est après, ni ce qui anime notre existence présente. Comment avons nous reçu la vie ? quel ressort la soutient ? comment notre cerveau a-t-il des idées et de la mémoire ? comment nos membres obéissent-ils incontinent à notre volonté ? etc. Nous n’en savons rien. Ce globe est-il seul habité ? a-t-il été fait après d’autres globes ou dans le même instant ? chaque genre de plantes vient-il ou non d’une première plante ? chaque genre d’animaux est-il produit ou non, par deux premiers animaux ? Les plus grands philosophes n’en savent pas plus sur ces matières que les plus ignorants des hommes. Il en faut revenir à ce proverbe populaire : « La poule a-t-elle été avant l’œuf, ou l’œuf avant la poule ? » Le proverbe est bas, mais il confond la plus haute sagesse, qui ne sait rien sur les premiers principes des choses sans un secours surnaturel. (*Note de Voltaire*, 1756)

Pour répondre à ta question « *comment est-ce qu'une étendue pourrait agir ?* », ici « étendue » est à prendre dans le sens de "*extent*", comme dans *"the extent of the human mind"*, la dimension maximale qu'une chose peut atteindre. Le sujet (sémantique) du verbe n'est donc pas une « étendue » mais plutôt « l'esprit, dans sa plus vaste étendue ».

Comment: Ah, right. I was wondering if there might be a semantic transposition going on: syntactically we need "the greatest extent of the mind", but semantically we need "the most expansive mind". I think the reason this intuitively confused me is because the inverted syntactic form we see *almost* yields this meaning in the first place, with only a slight tweak: *Que peut donc l'esprit le plus vastement étendu ?*

Comment: Three translations found: 1. *So what is the verdict of our greatest mind? Nothing: the book of fate is closed to us.* 2. *What is the verdict of the vastest mind? Silence: the book of fate is closed to us.* 3. *Mysteries like these can no man penetrate, Hid from his view remains the book of fate.*

Comment: @jlliagre So the idea of "the vastest mind" as in Teleporting Goat's last paragraph is confirmed. But why do you suppose "penetrate a mystery" is so prominent an option? I suppose it's just that "comprendre" is taken as the implied verb after "peut" instead of "faire" — et ce, à cause probablement du vers suivant ?

Comment: Both of the first translations are close to the original wording while the last one is taking many liberties with the source. It is unclear who actually did the translation. See https://voltairefoundation.wordpress.com/2021/12/02/marketing-voltaire-tobias-smollett-and-the-first-edition-of-voltaires-works-in-english-translation/